# AWS Quicksight Analysis not showing in console

Tags: amazon-web-services, visualization, amazon-quicksight

I am creating analysis using below code using boto3 python. I have created template using existing analysis and that template is being used to create another analysis, but just changing the dataset which has same schema.

```
# Create the new analysis based on the template
response = quicksight.create_analysis(
    AwsAccountId=account_id,
    AnalysisId=analysis_name.replace(' ', '-') + '_new',
    Name=analysis_name + '_new',
    SourceEntity={
        'SourceTemplate': {
            'Arn': template_arn,
            'DataSetReferences': data_set_references
        }
    },
    Permissions={["quicksight:UpdateAnalysisPermissions",
                  "quicksight:DeleteAnalysis",
                  "quicksight:DescribeAnalysisPermissions",
                  "quicksight:QueryAnalysis",
                  "quicksight:DescribeAnalysis",
                  "quicksight:CreateAnalysis"]}
)
```

I am also getting response as CREATION_SUCCESSFUL.

Response:

```
{
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        'RequestId': '50f0f62b-36a3-4287-923f-c717ca540671',
        'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
        'HTTPHeaders': {
            'date': 'Thu, 30 Mar 2023 15:27:41 GMT',
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'content-length': '1353',
            'connection': 'keep-alive',
            'x-amzn-requestid': '50f0f62b-36a3-4287-923f-c717ca540671'
        },
        'RetryAttempts': 0
    },
    'Status': 200,
    'Analysis': {
        'AnalysisId': 'tec_dspByCreative-analysis_new',
        'Arn': 'arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:{account-id}:analysis/tec_dspByCreative-analysis_new',
        'Name': 'tec_dspByCreative analysis_new',
        'Status': 'CREATION_SUCCESSFUL',
        'DataSetArns': ['arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:{account-id}:dataset/tec_dspByCreative', 'arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:{account-id}:dataset/tec_dspByProduct'],
        'CreatedTime': datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 30, 20, 55, 32, 233000, tzinfo = tzlocal()),
        'LastUpdatedTime': datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 30, 20, 55, 32, 804000, tzinfo = tzlocal()),
        'Sheets': [{
            'SheetId': '055a5755-66b0-48de-8dae-09d55f471626',
            'Name': 'Sheet 1'
        }, {
            'SheetId': '75786a78-35eb-4bfb-83c2-346e7ca25cce',
            'Name': 'Sheet 2'
        }]
    },
    'RequestId': '50f0f62b-36a3-4287-923f-c717ca540671'
}
```

But the analysis is not showing in AWS console. I am not able to figure out what might be the problem here.

When I am calling describe_analysis, its showing arn and status as creation_successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above is the permission issue. It is creating the Analysis in AWS Console which you can check in **Manage Quicksight -> Manage Assets** tab.

When you are creating analysis, Principal should be attached to it so that once the resource is created in AWS, it will be shared to that principal.

Since I didn't add any principal information, the resource is getting created because CLI credentials have permission to create resources.

Proper permissions are as follows:

```
            Permissions=[{
            'Principal': f'arn:aws:quicksight:{region}:{account_id}:user/default/{username}',
            'Actions': ['quicksight:RestoreAnalysis',
                        'quicksight:UpdateAnalysisPermissions',
                        'quicksight:DeleteAnalysis',
                        'quicksight:QueryAnalysis',
                        'quicksight:DescribeAnalysisPermissions',
                        'quicksight:DescribeAnalysis',
                        'quicksight:UpdateAnalysis']
        }]
    )
```